# Python UUID badly formed hexadecimal string

Tags: python, arcmap

Trying to generate a UUID based on an 6.6 XY coordinate pair and the date. However I am giving the function a 'badly formed hexadecimal UUID string'. Python noob plz help.

```
def LeID(Xv,Yv,Dv):
    import uuid
    import string
    import arcpy
    X_val = "%.6f" % Xv
    Y_val  = "%.6f" % Yv
    date = Dv
    xarr = string.split(X_val, '.')
    yarr = string.split(Y_val, '.')
    date = string.split(date , '/')
    val =  str(xarr[0] + xarr[1] + yarr[0] + yarr[1] + date[0]  + date[1] + date[2] )
    return '{' + str(uuid.UUID(val).time_low()) + '}'
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It won't work the way you think.

There are several types of [UUID](http://docs.python.org/release/2.6.7/library/uuid.html): based on time (UUID1), randomly (UUID4) or based on another UUID plus data, put together via MD5 (UUID3) or SHA1 (UUID5).

So you would take one previously defined UUID, maybe `UUID('f82aa75f-56a8-442b-89d2-eb7aaae6f9c3')`, as a namespace and derive all from this.

```
def LeID(Xv,Yv,Dv):
    import uuid
    import string
    import arcpy
    MyNS = uuid.UUID('f82aa75f-56a8-442b-89d2-eb7aaae6f9c3')
    X_val = "%.6f" % Xv
    Y_val  = "%.6f" % Yv
    date = Dv
    xarr = string.split(X_val, '.')
    yarr = string.split(Y_val, '.')
    date = string.split(date , '/')
    val =  str(xarr[0] + xarr[1] + yarr[0] + yarr[1] + date[0]  + date[1] + date[2] )
    print MyNS, repr(val) # for debugging
    return '{' + str(uuid.uuid5(MyNS, val)) + '}'
```

Comment: please add my newly added print line in order to find out what goes into the `uuid` engine.